# Object inside of same object

Tags: java, object

I want to store object inside of object and idea is to save every previous condition of it so I could implement undo option. I know that this problem could be solved with lists but I am interested in this particular solution.

I have class:

```
public class Condition {

  private String name;
  private Condition last_condition;

  public Condition(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void changeName(String name){

    if(last_condition == null){
      last_condition = new Condition(this.name);
      this.name = name;
      return;
    }

    while(last_condition != null){
    last_condition = last_condition.last_condition;
  }

  last_condition = new Condition(this.name);
  his.name = name;
  }
}
```

I believe that problem is in this part:

```
last_condition = last_condition.last_condition;
```

but I don't understand completely why. I think it is something up to null pointer being saved in variable. Since someone coming from C this looks kind of natural. This is just simple representation of class, I also tried with some temporary variables but results are same.

**EDIT:**
When I call this method for example 4 times, it is not saving all 4 changes. So there is no compile errors, it just don't function correctly.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: What exactly is the bug?

Comment: Is this for a UI program? Or for what? Perhaps you can use an API, for example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, it is not error, but when I call this method for example 4 times, it is not saving all 4 changes.

Comment: How are you using your method?

Comment: Calling it from main few times, every time with different string as argument.

Comment: What you have here is a linked list... But anyway, what is `his`? Where is it defined?

Comment: Try while last_condition.last_condition != null in the while loop and then last_condition.last_condition = new...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it harder than necessary. You don't need to iterate through all the previous conditions. All you need is

```
public void changeName(String name){
    Condition copy = new Condition(this.name);
    copy.lastCondition = this.lastCondition;
    this.lastCondition = copy;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: I need iteration if I don't want to have fix number of previous states.

Comment: No, you don't. If you call changeName 345 times, the above code will create a linked list of 345 Condition instances.